# How to add colors to vuetify table row

Tags: colors, row, vuetify.js, tablerow, v-data-table

This is my vuetify table.

---------template-----------

```
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"

    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
  </v-data-table>
```

------script-------------

```
headers: [
          {
            text: 'Campaign Id',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'id',
          },
          { text: 'Created by', value: 'created' },
          { text: 'Controls', value: 'control' },
        ],
desserts: [
          {
            id: '1',
            created:'ABBC',
             control:''
          },
        {
            id: '2',
            created:'ABBC',
             control: '',
          },
     ]
```

I want to add colors to table row, as row after row. how I  do this?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you this solution. https://codepen.io/lino96/pen/yLaRGmX?editors=101

Code HTML

```
   <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          :items-per-page="5"
          class="elevation-1"
          :item-class="(item) => item.class">
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </div>
```

Code JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
            text: 'Campaign Id',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'id',
        },
        { text: 'Created by', value: 'created' },
        { text: 'Controls', value: 'control' },
      ],
      desserts: [
          {
            id: '1',
            created:'ABBC',
            control:'',
            class: 'purple darken-1 white--text'
          },
          {
            id: '2',
            created:'ABBC',
            control: '',
            class: 'yellow darken-2'
          },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: when we delete some item , not got colors as row after row. because item deleting with their index. I want to add color with item index

Comment: your best bet would then be to add a class property to the list. Then you put the class that suits you. I have modify my code to illustrate this.